# I'm seeing strange ActionLink behaviour, why is the url displayed in the browser not displaying the seemingly correct controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, html.actionlink, asp.net-core-routing

I have the following `ActionLink`:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Upload", "Upload", "File")
```

yet when I hover over the link, the url displayed in the browser is `http://localhost:44334/Upload`. Where is the controller in this url? Strangely, clicking the url takes me to my `File/Upload` view, and yet stranger, the url displayed in the browser's address bar is `https://localhost:44334/Upload`.

The `ActionLink` is on page `Home/Explorer`, so AFAIK a controller name is normally necessary.

Why is the `ActionLink` helper leaving out the controller name, and why is the link still working? I have tried refreshing the page with cache clearing, with no difference. I don't know what else do besides leave it alone because it works, but I'm concerned this is some quirk and it will no longer work when I deploy my site.

My routing is still standard, out-of-box, in the `Startup` class's `Configure` method:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Strangely enough, I have now added a `Download` link each row of an HTML table of files, looking like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", "File", new { filePath = file.Path })
```

and this link also renders without the controller name, e.g:

```
https://localhost/Download?filePath=....
```

Comment: Have you defined a specific route definition for it?

Comment: do you have an entry in routeconfig that has "upload" in url parameter, and "file" and "upload" in controller and action respectively in other parameter?

Comment: Without route definition in `RouteConfig` it's difficult to tell if the route definition or route order is wrong. It is possible that a route defined without controller name in URL but has default values to controller and action name parameter.

Comment: You obviously have a route defined with `url: "Upload"` with `defaults: new { controller = "File" ...}` (or the equivalent `RouteAttribute`)

Comment: I have changed no routing at all. It is still exactly as output my the MVC Application project template. I have now showed the routing in my question.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I don't **obviously** have any `Upload` route defined, as explained in the edited question.

Comment: Can you include the declaration of your action used for upload and any attributes defined on it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Http{Verb}("{routeTemplae}")` is usually used when building a REST API. In order to be able to generate URLs for the default MVC controllers when using attribute routing you will need to use `Route` attribute.

The original controller probably did not have a route prefix which meant that

```
//POST /Upload //<-- when there is no prefix on the controller
[HttpPost("Upload")]
```

on the controller would route to `/Upload` with no controller prefix.

By including a prefix for the route on the controller it will include the controller name when generating URLs when using attribute routing.

```
[Route("[controller]"]
public class FileController : Controller {
    //POST File/Upload
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Upload")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Upload(UploadFilesViewModel model, IEnumerable<IFormFile> files) {
        //...
    }

    //GET File/Download
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Download")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Download(string filePath) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Reference [Routing in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing)

Reference [Routing to Controller Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

Comment: You are dead right, thanks, my friend. I don't need the `Route` attribute, but you are correct, as I said in my own answer below, that `[HttpPost("Upload")]` routes straight to `/Upload`. You are a winner.

Comment: Just wanted to show that it could still work with attribute routing seeing as you mentioned that you were using the default convention-based routing.

Answer (score 3):

This is most strange, but in my `FileController`, I had leftover attribute routing from when I was using the the controller for a Web API instead of in the MVC web application. The methods essentially looked like this:

```
[HttpPost("Upload")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Upload(UploadFilesViewModel model, IEnumerable<IFormFile> files)

[HttpGet("Download")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Download(string filePath)
```

Now that I have removed the route names from the attributes, and have just plain `[HttpPost]` and `[HttpGet]`, the actionlinks work correctly and render URLs that now do contain the controller name.

Answer (score 0):

[HttpPost("Upload")]

Here Using POST method so no need of prefix like '**/**' on MVC controller

[HttpGet("Download")]
public async Task Download(string filePath)